# Calendar API - setting quotaUser parameter with Calendar API v3 C# library

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

Our application is performing requests to Calendar API using domain-wide delegation.
We had no problem with that until sometime ago (and we still have no problem in our development computer), but now requests proceeding from our server are taking several minutes to be served, if at all. I’ve found [this page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/quota#proper_accounting_with_service_accounts) explaining the problem and how to solve it by setting the **quotaUser** URL parameter. We’re using **Calendar API v3 C#** library and we’ve tried to simply set quotaUser to an arbitrary string (see code below). Unfortunately this has not solved the problem. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
var listOfUsersEmails = //someListOfEmails;
CalendarService service = GetCalendarService("credentials.json", gSuiteAdminEmail);
var events = new Events();
events.Items = new List<Event>();

var request = new BatchRequest(service);
foreach (var userEmail in listOfUsersEmails)
{
    var r = service.Events.List(userEmail);
    r.TimeMin = //today's beginning;
    r.TimeMax = //today's end
    r.ShowDeleted = false;
    r.SingleEvents = true;
    r.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
    
    // this is what we've tried
    r.QuotaUser = userEmail.Substring(0,40);
    // 

    request.Queue<Events>(
        r,
    (content, error, i, message) =>
    {
        if (content != null && content.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (var f in content.Items)
            {
                events.Items.Add(f);
            }
        }
    });
}
await request.ExecuteAsync();
return events;
```

Here is the screenshot that @Daniel asked for (see comments below):
[image: GCP quotas for project]

Comment: Have you checked the GCP project's API quotas, and are you getting any errors there? Do you have a screenshot? `quotaUser` will prevent the service account from running out of quota by assigning it to the user being impersonated, but the project itself also has its own quota.

Comment: Hi, @Daniel, please see edited question with a screenshot from GCP Calendar API quotas for the project. I don't think we're exceeding this; as I said when we run the app from a development computer, using the same project, response times drop to less than a tenth.